# Splash server with Docker not running on Mac

Tags: docker, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

I am trying to configure a Splash server with Docker in order to render javascript for scrapy.

I downloaded and installed Docker Toolbox (The latest version of Docker does not install on my Macbook pro 2009 due to lack of CPU MMU support).

I runned "docker run -p 5023:5023 -p 8050:8050 -p 8051:8051 scrapinghub/splash" in Docker Quickstart Terminal. The command performs but after "Starting factory..." I can not get my shell prompt back.

I tried to access http://localhost:8050/ in my browser and to ping localhost:8050 but this does not work: "This site can’t be reached". I would appreciate any help to understand what is the problem. Thank you!

```
                        ##         .
                  ## ## ##        ==
               ## ## ## ## ##    ===
           /"""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
      ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~
           \______ o           __/
             \    \         __/
              \____\_______/


docker is configured to use the default machine with IP 192.168.99.100
For help getting started, check out the docs at https://docs.docker.com

Ordinateur:~ jb$ docker run -p 5023:5023 -p 8050:8050 -p 8051:8051 scrapinghub/splash
Unable to find image 'scrapinghub/splash:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from scrapinghub/splash
75c416ea735c: Pull complete 
c6ff40b6d658: Pull complete 
a7050fc1f338: Pull complete 
f0ffb5cf6ba9: Pull complete 
be232718519c: Pull complete 
de1c9f88de34: Pull complete 
0b8cdf21020f: Pull complete 
cf35f91dcdb5: Pull complete 
bfbc20b51f2f: Pull complete 
f434ae0e9eb2: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:0a91eb2de229289b0c83f39d8bd079d2464a954001869417a5297aa60820af5b
Status: Downloaded newer image for scrapinghub/splash:latest
2017-07-26 10:45:59+0000 [-] Log opened.
2017-07-26 10:45:59.513146 [-] Splash version: 3.0
2017-07-26 10:45:59.515698 [-] Qt 5.9.1, PyQt 5.9, WebKit 602.1, sip 4.19.3, Twisted 16.1.1, Lua 5.2
2017-07-26 10:45:59.516027 [-] Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
2017-07-26 10:45:59.516214 [-] Open files limit: 1048576
2017-07-26 10:45:59.516349 [-] Can't bump open files limit
2017-07-26 10:45:59.657299 [-] Xvfb is started: ['Xvfb', ':806019943', '-screen', '0', '1024x768x24', '-nolisten', 'tcp']
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
2017-07-26 10:45:59.992921 [-] proxy profiles support is enabled, proxy profiles path: /etc/splash/proxy-profiles
2017-07-26 10:46:00.273110 [-] verbosity=1
2017-07-26 10:46:00.273490 [-] slots=50
2017-07-26 10:46:00.275082 [-] argument_cache_max_entries=500
2017-07-26 10:46:00.276541 [-] Web UI: enabled, Lua: enabled (sandbox: enabled)
2017-07-26 10:46:00.278098 [-] Site starting on 8050
2017-07-26 10:46:00.278647 [-] Starting factory <twisted.web.server.Site object at 0x7f751d78ccf8>
```

If I restart docker and run "docker ps" I can see that the container is running:

```
Ordinateur:~ jb$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                      NAMES
e2c23b576b88        scrapinghub/splash   "python3 /app/bin/..."   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:5023->5023/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8050-8051->8050-8051/tcp   gallant_feynman
```

Comment: if you start the docker in inspect mode you get some error? docker start -i gallant_feynman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker is available at address other than localhost. From your logs:

> docker is configured to use the default machine with IP 192.168.99.100

Try accessing http://192.168.99.100:8050 instead of localhost. If you're using docker-machine, you can also get an ip address using `docker-machine ip default` command.

Answer (score 0):

The server was running normally, I just had to replace localhost by my IP. Thank you!